# osgi same class but classcastexception

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse

Getting an issue where class A cannot be cast to class A in osgi. Point is this class A is not being exported in any other bundle as well as where it is created. In the pom for exported-package it is mentioned "!A" so A is not exported. Still we get the issue. A re-install of the bundle works though. Cant recreate the issue and then suddenly it is back again . Any ideas.

The class is an entity class and internal - not in any other project

In maven-bundle-plugin we have

```
<Private-Package>
  com.xxx.yyy.entity.*
</Private-Package>
<Export-Package>
  !com.xxx.yyy.entity.*
</Export-Package>
```

Comment: We are using java with camel and running on jboss-fuse.

Comment: It is only the same class if the class objects are ==. That is, object1.getClass() == object2.getClass(). It does not matter to the VM if the classes were loaded from the exact same class file.

Comment: Can you verify the manifest file for the exports? You assume it's not exported based on the Maven configuration, but is really not in the manifest?

Comment: Have checked in the manifest. It is not there.

Comment: <Private-Package>
    com.xxx.yyy.entity.*
    </Private-Package>
    <Export-Package>
    !com.xxx.yyy.entity.*
    </Export-Package>

Is the above alright and necessary ? I thought if you mention private-package then you shouldn't need to mention a "!" in export-package for same bundle.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues when we used technologies that had String-Class caches without direct wiring to the bundle of the Class.

Let's say there is Bundle A and Bundle T (technology). Bundle A is updated and but the classes that were loaded during the first time Bundle A was started are still in the cache of Bundle T.

This can become really magical if there is a technology in the OSGi container that updates bundles during their restart. One typical case is when a technology wants to do bytecode manipulation on classes. It implements a Bundle Weaving Hook, but it must update all of the relevant bundles that were started before the magical technology bundle to be able to catch the classloadings. An example of such magical technology is Apache Aries Proxy.

Btw.: A stacktrace and some source code would help a lot to see in which technology the issue appears.